# Java - Keyframe extraction from a video

Tags: java, video-processing, xuggle

I want to extract keyframes from a video.
Now I'm using a loop that compare the samples of one frame with the samples of the preceding frame, but this method isn't very good.

Let me explain: I have a surveillance video and I have to select the frames where there is a change (a person appears, another person appears, a person goes away, etc.) Now I'm using this class to compare frames: [Java Image Comparison / Motion Detection Class](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html)

Do you know other ways?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you call a "*keyframe*". Your method would allow you only to find scene transitions, but that is not what is usually meant by a "keyframe" in video decoding: it's rather usually an [I-frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types#Intra_coded_frames_.28or_slices_or_I.E2.80.91frames_or_Key_frames.29) (a frame which can be decoded on its own, without reference to other frames). (Frequently scene transitions are keyframes, but no necessarily the other way). This concept it tied to the video codec, of course, but most modern codecs (from MPEG-1) implement this concept. But notice that this is not related to the raw pictures in themselves, but with the codec.

If you want to detect these keyframes *(I-frames)*, then you must look inside your video decoding API, to see if it allows you to get this information. It seems that xuggle provides you the [IVideoPicture.getPictureType()](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IVideoPicture.html) method, but I have not used it.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation but I'm searching a method to find scene transitions, let me explain:

I have a surveillance video and I have to select the frames where there is a change (a person appears, another person appears, a person goes away, etc.) 

Now I'm using this class to compare frames: http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html

Comment: Do you want to want to do it in real time or in batch mode? Why do you sat hat "this method isn't very good"?

Comment: I want to do it in batch mode.
This method isn't very good because if my video show a running person, this method extracts every frame of the video because it find too many differences between two frames.
This is the reason because I'm searching for other ways to do the keyframe extraction.

Comment: Ask/search for "scene transition" or "shot transition", then; not for "keyframe", as this is other concept. See eg here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_transition_detection

Comment: Simple pixel difference, with a suitable threshold and some pre-post filtering, is frequently enough. I did that once, (using avisynth http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/ScriptClip) with quite good results.